# Share a discriminated union or interface with data and function arguments

Tags: typescript

I have some event code that looks something like this:

```js
send(event, payload) { ... }

handleEvent({ data }) {
  switch (data.type) {
    case 'ONE':
      console.log('strings:', data.payload.split(' '));
    case 'TWO':
      console.log('double:', data.payload * 2);
  }
}
```

I would like to create a type/interface that could be used on the arguments of `send` and the data in `handleEvent`.

I can type the events in `send` like so:

```js
interface Message {
  [MessageType.ONE]: string;
  [MessageType.TWO]: number;
}

type MessageKey = string & keyof Message;
function send<K extends MessageKey>(event: K, payload: Message[K]): void { ... }
```

And I can type the data in `handleEvent` like so:

```js
enum MessageType {
  ONE = 'ONE',
  TWO = 'TWO'
}

type Message = {
  type: MessageType.ONE;
  payload: string;
} | {
  type: MessageType.TWO;
  payload: number;
}
```

Is there a nice way I to apply a single type or interface to both? I prefer the interface route, as the formatting is clear and concise.

You can [see it in action on the TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAssDO8CGBzYAVAngB2FA3gFBRQDyAcgKJQC8UA5BZfQDTFToDqptDXp9QgF9CASxAAXYACcAZkgDGeOIlR4iJANorkaLLgB0TALoAuKPAnTxKANzttCXRhzAD-M1HAQARjPsihBKusE5qAKogogD2ILwaUMG45jpq+m5M9iTYSJgANtFIACbmltYgdsJQAD4E7EnAKWF6ru7cWVA5+YUlXpB+0gGEQSGpaADSwJi8ZTZQAGRQANZT0bKhqmj2smAgChIxcfCgRQA841DAAB5SIEXwG86TmAB8ABTAAG6gEubjLJ1cgVik1NsBNONjABKcyfaKiIp1EgKWLwaJ5NwFFBvejHO42ViXb6SAFdYFFKFDQg7PYHWJQAAWSDuGMoxIkH3Z5nwUCKSAkSFBzkihygQhhUDhCKRUBRIEsBF5-KQYt4Xx+HXgAHdRBIFAyoG8+QKDA0oTLkUhjo80q0mKZ2CRkaj0ZjotjcVYbPBTITjUgDGSegZ4Ng8rqcQwoZTHU6fNJgEglh1Ldaxi5DPwHU6nXK0RiDFicUVomAfBjfQD-YGgT0oAAqKAAJhjOZI8cTyfYIkCeKKb3T6SMVAB9AZwDyBSgWui0jyRXolKgAHpl2RxoQ+wPmhmMiBgACACyHperqCUABKF9IF6AA).

Comment: I'm not sure I fully follow, but you can [derive the union from the interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAssDO8CGBzYAVAngB2FA3gFBRQDyAcgKJQC8UA5BZfQDTFToDqptDXp9QgF9CASxAAXYACcAZkgDGeOIlR4iJANorkaLLgB0TALoAuKPAnTxKANzttCXRhzAD-M1HAQARjPsihBKusE5qAKogogD2ILwaUAD0iVAAegD87MG45jpq+m5M9iTYSJgANtFIACbmltYgdsJQAD4EWa65YXqu7tzFUKUVVbVekH7SAYRBIXlo8KSyADzoAHzxUJoA0lDiUADWwJjRshye+FDZwOZbLINllTXm6NvGUELvmofHp+jG01coAARGSiABuwGqc2AkRicTo0IWy2hq3syRIaUyQA)

Comment: Example using the [union only route](https://tsplay.dev/m35QAw).

Comment: @spender That's exactly what I was looking for. Can you post that as a response so I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: @kellys That answer is equally correct and awesome, but I do prefer the interface route since it is the easier of the two to maintain in my situation. I will definitely keep your solution at hand for other uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have an object of type:

```
type O = {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}
```

A (slightly long-winded) way to extract a union of the types of the values of an object is as follows:

```
type V = { [K in keyof O]: O[K] }[keyof O]; // string | number
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8lC8UDeAoKUCGAuKBnYATgJYB2A5gNxpQBGOJArgLY0QFUC+KKokUAagmRQA2gGkopKAGsIIAPYAzWAF0cMcSqgcRshcpgqqAemPooAPQD8QA)

however, by going this long-winded route, with a small modification we now have the tools to map an object type `T` to a union of mapped types:

```
type MessagesOf<T> = { [K in keyof T]: { type: K, payload: T[K] } }[keyof T]
```

which can be used to map your `Message` interface:

```
enum MessageType {
  ONE = 'ONE',
  TWO = 'TWO'
}

interface Message {
  [MessageType.ONE]: string;
  [MessageType.TWO]: number;
}

type DerivedMessageUnion = MessagesOf<Message>;
```

to a type that is equivalent to:

```
| {
    type: MessageType.ONE;
    payload: string;
  } 
| {
    type: MessageType.TWO;
    payload: number;
  }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAssDO8CGBzYAVAngB2FA3gFBRQDyAcgKJQC8UA5BZfQDTFToDqptDXp9QgF9CASxAAXYACcAZkgDGeOIlR4iJANorkaLLgB0TALoAuKPAnTxKANzttCXRhzAD-M1HAQARjPsihBKusE5q8KSyADzoAHy8+FCaANJQ4lAA1sCYAPayHJ6JwbjmySxQ2EiYADY5SAAm5ugpxlBCbZpZufnoxoRBIQAiMqIAbsD1OmoAqiCiOSC8U2gR0cvAsfYA9FskUAB6APyEQA)